# Compare two rows of a sheet to another and show characteristics

Tags: google-sheets

I'll try to be clear although english is not my first language. I have a first spreadsheet (let's name it PRODUCTS) containing, in different columns, characteristics of different products (Company/S.N./Quality). As:

[image: PRODUCTS]

And on a second spreadsheet (INVENTORY), I can see what we have in stock.

[image: INVENTORY]

I would like to be able to see the quality of each of the products we have in stock. Like in this image:
[image]

I tried some kinds of IF and ArrayFormula... I understand it should be an easy problem, but I'm not a clever man.

Answer (score 2):

There are cleverer ways of doing this but the conventional solution is to add a 'helper' column:

- Insert a column at the extreme left of PRODUCTS and in A1:

  ```
  =B1&"|"&C1
  ```

and copy down to suit.

- In INVENTORY in C2 insert:

  ```
  =VLOOKUP(A2&"|"&B2,Products!A:D,4,0)
  ```

and copy down to suit.